# One user seem to be posting from (at least) four accounts, please help to sort it out

Tags: support, user-accounts

It looks like an (unexperienced?) user creates new account each time they lose prior one. Accounts that seem to be their are:

- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/13670/newboss
  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/14140/newboss
  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/14197/newboss
  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/14211/newboss

There may be more, it is rather difficult for a regular user to find out.

Questions posted from above accounts so far are:

- [How to earn the respect of a team that is frustrated by and skeptical about change?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18248/how-to-earn-the-respect-of-a-team-that-is-frustrated-by-and-skeptical-about-chan)
  [Should I stay irreplaceable in the company by keeping all skills to myself?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18249/should-i-stay-irreplaceable-in-the-company-by-keeping-all-skills-to-myself)
  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18498/what-can-i-do-when-my-staff-dislikes-me-and-is-explicit-about-it
  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18531/how-to-respond-when-my-senior-staff-is-constantly-negative-towards-me
  [How to prevent a mutiny by the senior employees whom I manage?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18536/how-to-prevent-a-mutiny-by-the-senior-employees-whom-i-manage)

Can this be somehow sorted out?

It is especially troublesome that some questions seem to be related or duplicates but it's hard to handle this as accounts differ.

**Update** - as pointed in the [comments](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/one-user-seem-to-be-posting-from-at-least-four-accounts-please-help-to-sort-i?noredirect=1#comment3736_2291), one particular [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7389) suggests that there's yet another account - https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/14262/user14262

---

**Update2** - checking my older flags, discovered two more accounts worth checking:

- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/13141/newboss83

  - posted question:
    [How to deal with dramatic and over-alarmed employees?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17883/how-to-deal-with-dramatic-and-over-alarmed-employees)
- https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/13170/newboss83

  - posted deleted answer:
    [How to deal with dramatic and over-alarmed employees?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17883/how-to-deal-with-dramatic-and-over-alarmed-employees/17913#17913)

Comment: Side note: All of the 'users' are unregistered. So every time the OP comes back to a question of theirs they end up making a new account for each edit, being that they cant log in to edit the previous iteration

Comment: @RhysW What is an unregistered user?

Comment: He has just made [an additional suggested edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/14262/user14262) from yet another unregistered account...

Comment: Looks like that account is registered and should be the main account. I think.

Comment: @geekrunnings a user who has not registered an account into the SE network

Comment: @gnat seems the merge has been made, thanks to whoever did so

Comment: @RhysW can't tell if it's complete, of accounts I listed http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/13670/newboss seems to be still hanging while the rest indeed looks like merged into http://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/14262/newboss